# Unable to load gensim Fasttext model - UTF-8 unicode error

Tags: python, encoding, pickle, gensim, fasttext

I have trained FastText model for french language using Gensim library.
Suddenly, this trained model is not getting loaded into memory.

I am using below code :-

```
from gensim.models import FastText
fname = "filename"
model = FastText.load(fname)
```

and it throws following error : -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/fasttext.py", line 1070, in load
    model = super(FastText, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
    model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
    return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 426, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1384, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 14072054: invalid start byte
```

As this model is trained on large dataset, is there any way to recover/load this model?

Comment: "Suddenly, this trained model is not getting loaded into memory." -> this implies that it used to work correctly?  Has someone or some program changed the file?

Comment: Yes, It was working fine and the model gets retrained frequently. @snakecharmerb

Answer (score -1):

This error means that the text stored in your model does not adhere to the `utf-8` encoding, as explained [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q10-loading-a-word2vec-model-fails-with-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-).

A solution with an already trained model would be to set `unicode_errors` flag when running the model:

```
from gensim.models import FastText
fname = "filename"
model = FastText.load(fname, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

This will, however, result in ignoring the words/characters in question, which may not be ideal.

Better would be to re-train the model using `utf-8` compliant setup, but it would require re-training.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I tried "model = FastText.load(fname, unicode_errors='ignore')"  but there is no such paramter. Next time, we will re-train the model with utf-8 compliant setup, but is there any chance to recover this model and can be used as it was working earlier ?